# how to do column stacking using css in wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress

i have 2 rows and both rows have 3 columns each having 3 blurbs. what i want to do is that when i make it responsive and lower the resolution at a point these two rows should be converted to 3 rows having two column each instead of having three columns. All using the CSS please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do this without either a) manipulating the DOM tree with JS dynamically, or b) code up your all your different rows with the correct amount of columns to show for each viewport and then hide and show (swap) these at a certain breakpoint with a media query.

With JS you could avoid duplicating html markup. A pure CSS solution will not be possible without duplicating the markup/content.

For b) your would start with your 2 rows x 3 cols visible and the 3 rows x 2 cols would be hidden with `display: none;`. Then, as your viewport narrows down you would hide the visible rows with a `display: none;` for each and reveal the three hidden rows with a `display: block;` on each of them.

Comment: yes after trying so much came to know that your insyructions are helping out thanks,